# Projects similar to SCAP Security Guide

Tags: compliance, automation

Are there any other projects similar to what SCAP Security Guide (SSG) is doing? Automated security policy compliance using Ansible playbooks and Bash scripts.

I'm trying to put my systems in compliance with CIS and STIG, but CIS only provide PDFs with the policies and no automated content, and SSG doesn't have the STIGs for some products like the Apache HTTP Server.